# Getting client private ip with javascript

Tags: javascript, ip

My mobile is connected to a WiFi router and it gives me 192.168.1.100 as my private IP. Now I have a requirement where I have to get this IP for some purpose. When I visit this "http://l2.io/ip.js" it gives me back the public IP i.e. "140.242.241.2".

So bottom line is how can I get the IP address which the router assigns me with the help of javascript. Any working example will be of great help.

Comment: Is the page where you need the ip hosted in your local network, or is it on the web?

Comment: Sounds related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: I have gone through the post already and did not help. So posted a new question.

Comment: D.kasipovic.. I Dont have any pages. I need info about how to get private IP which is assigned by router with the help of javascript